# Cross origin request with AJAX, JQuery, Apache & basic authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, cors

After spend many hours on Google and Stackoverflow without feeling of progress, I'm asking help to make cross request ajax working.

I have JQuery on client side with a custom configuration for basic authentication :

```
//configuration AJAX  
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {   
    xhr.withCredentials = true;  
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmZyOmF6ZXJ0eQ==");  
});

//a request
$.get("http://domainA.com/api");
```

On my server, Apache is configured to respond with special cors headers:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domainB.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Request-Headers "Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "86400"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

So, when the request is send, AJAX made a preflight request :

```
OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1
Host: domainA.com
User-Agent: useragent
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: domainB.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Connection: keep-alive
```

And my server respond with :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 15:58:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domainB.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 489
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

And the AJAX request stops without doing the real request. The returned code is 0. I can't find what is the problem in my configuration as any `Access-Control-Request` has its response. Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure the GET request is not being sent?  What are you seeing in your browser's console?

Comment: the preflight request and  its response are the only things I can see in the developer tools. After the preflight request, the request ends and returns code 0.

Comment: was this ever resolved? I have the same problem right now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867663/how-and-where-to-implement-basic-authentication-in-kibana-3

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this? It works fine on my Apache server:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin"
```

Use `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` instead of `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.