# How and where to implement basic authentication in Kibana 3

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I have put my elasticsearch server behind a Apache reverse proxy that provides basic authentication.

Authenticating to Apache directly from the browser works fine. However, when I use Kibana 3 to access the server, I receive authentication errors.

Obviously because no auth headers are sent along with Kibana's Ajax calls.

I added the below to elastic-angular-client.js in the Kibana vendor directory to implement authentication quick and dirty. But for some reason it does not work.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
```

What is the best approach and place to implement basic authentication in Kibana?

```
/*! elastic.js - v1.1.1 - 2013-05-24
 * https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js
 * Copyright (c) 2013 FullScale Labs, LLC; Licensed MIT */

/*jshint browser:true */
/*global angular:true */
'use strict';

/* 
Angular.js service wrapping the elastic.js API. This module can simply
be injected into your angular controllers. 
*/
angular.module('elasticjs.service', [])
  .factory('ejsResource', ['$http', function ($http) {

  return function (config) {
    var

      // use existing ejs object if it exists
      ejs = window.ejs || {},

      /* results are returned as a promise */
      promiseThen = function (httpPromise, successcb, errorcb) {
        return httpPromise.then(function (response) {
          (successcb || angular.noop)(response.data);
          return response.data;
        }, function (response) {
          (errorcb || angular.noop)(response.data);
          return response.data;
        });
      };

    // check if we have a config object
    // if not, we have the server url so
    // we convert it to a config object
    if (config !== Object(config)) {
      config = {server: config};
    }

    // set url to empty string if it was not specified
    if (config.server == null) {
      config.server = '';
    }

    /* implement the elastic.js client interface for angular */
    ejs.client = {
      server: function (s) {
        if (s == null) {
          return config.server;
        }

        config.server = s;
        return this;
      },
      post: function (path, data, successcb, errorcb) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
        console.log($http.defaults.headers);
        path = config.server + path;
        var reqConfig = {url: path, data: data, method: 'POST'};
        return promiseThen($http(angular.extend(reqConfig, config)), successcb, errorcb);
      },
      get: function (path, data, successcb, errorcb) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
        path = config.server + path;
        // no body on get request, data will be request params
        var reqConfig = {url: path, params: data, method: 'GET'};
        return promiseThen($http(angular.extend(reqConfig, config)), successcb, errorcb);
      },
      put: function (path, data, successcb, errorcb) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
        path = config.server + path;
        var reqConfig = {url: path, data: data, method: 'PUT'};
        return promiseThen($http(angular.extend(reqConfig, config)), successcb, errorcb);
      },
      del: function (path, data, successcb, errorcb) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
        path = config.server + path;
        var reqConfig = {url: path, data: data, method: 'DELETE'};
        return promiseThen($http(angular.extend(reqConfig, config)), successcb, errorcb);
      },
      head: function (path, data, successcb, errorcb) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password');
        path = config.server + path;
        // no body on HEAD request, data will be request params
        var reqConfig = {url: path, params: data, method: 'HEAD'};
        return $http(angular.extend(reqConfig, config))
          .then(function (response) {
          (successcb || angular.noop)(response.headers());
          return response.headers();
        }, function (response) {
          (errorcb || angular.noop)(undefined);
          return undefined;
        });
      }
    };

    return ejs;
  };
}]);
```

**UPDATE 1:** I implemented Matts suggestion. However, the server returns a weird response. It seems that the authorization header is not working. Could it have to do with the fact, that I am running Kibana on port 81 and elasticsearch on 8181?

```
OPTIONS /solar_vendor/_search HTTP/1.1
Host: 46.252.46.173:8181
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://46.252.46.173:81
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2013 23:47:02 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Username/Password"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 346
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**UPDATE 2:** Updated all instances with the modified headers in these Kibana files

```
root@localhost:/var/www/kibana# grep -r 'ejsResource(' .

./src/app/controllers/dash.js:      $scope.ejs = ejsResource({server: config.elasticsearch, headers: {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Accept, Origin, Authorization', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='}});
./src/app/services/querySrv.js:    var ejs = ejsResource({server: config.elasticsearch, headers: {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Accept, Origin, Authorization', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='}});
./src/app/services/filterSrv.js:    var ejs = ejsResource({server: config.elasticsearch, headers: {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Accept, Origin, Authorization', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='}});
./src/app/services/dashboard.js:    var ejs = ejsResource({server: config.elasticsearch, headers: {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Accept, Origin, Authorization', 'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=='}});
```

And modified my vhost conf for the reverse proxy like this

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9200/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:9200/

    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName “Username/Password”
        AuthUserFile /var/www/cake2.2.4/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin, Accept, Authorization"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=0"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

    </Location>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache sends back the new response headers but the request header still seems to be wrong somewhere. Authentication just doesn't work.

Request Headers

```
OPTIONS /solar_vendor/_search HTTP/1.1
Host: 46.252.26.173:8181
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://46.252.26.173:81
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Sat, 09 Nov 2013 08:48:48 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Username/Password"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 346
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**SOLUTION:**
After doing some more research, I found out that this is definitely a configuration issue with regard to CORS. There are quite a few posts available regarding that topic but it appears that in order to solve my problem, it would be necessary to to make some very granular configurations on apache and also make sure that the right stuff is sent from the browser.

So I reconsidered the strategy and found a much simpler solution. Just modify the vhost reverse proxy config to move the elastisearch server AND kibana on the same http port. This also adds even better security to Kibana.

This is what I did:

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /bigdatadesk/ http://127.0.0.1:81/bigdatadesk/src/
ProxyPassReverse /bigdatadesk/ http://127.0.0.1:81/bigdatadesk/src/

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9200/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:9200/


    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName “Username/Password”
        AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your suggested final solution works like a charm and is plain and simple. Much prefer that over the various github application proxy projects which are in different states of development and scarcely documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Kibana, replace the existing elastic-angular-client.js with the latest which can be found [here](https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js/blob/master/src/clients/elastic-angular-client.js).  Then, in the Kibana code replace all instances of:

```
$scope.ejs = ejsResource(config.elasticsearch);
```

with

```
$scope.ejs = ejsResource({server: config.elasticsearch, headers: {'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'accept, origin, authorization', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64Encode('user:Password')}});
```

That should be all you need.

Update:

Is apache configured for for CORS?  See [this](http://www.eyelock.net/blog/archives/430).

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin, Accept, Authorization"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=0"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Comment: I updated the client and changed the instances. For some reason I am seeing a similar behaviour compared to my original approach: I'll post the request header and response headers from the latest POST request in my initial question for reference.

Comment: I added a new request header and some apache settings.

Comment: @MattWeber where is elastic-angular-client.js file located in kibana distribution? I couldn't locate it.

Comment: @erbdex I think 'here', after a bit of digging, now points to http://www.eyelock.net/blog/2011/12/08/a-simple-cross-origin-resource-sharing-example-explained.html

Answer (score 10):

Here is a perfect solution:

https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy

Support not only basicAuth backend, but also GoogleOAuth and BasicAuth for the client.
If works, please give a star, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that it's a CORS issue. Kibana 3 uses CORS to communicate with ElasticSearch.

In order to enable HTTP Authentication Headers and Cookies to be sent with the Kibana CORS requests you need to do two things:

ONE: In your Kibana config.js file, find the setting where your ElasticSearch server is defined:

`elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200",`

This needs to be changed to:

`elasticsearch: {server: "http://localhost:9200", withCredentials: true},`

This will tell Kibana to send the Authentication headers and cookies IF the server is capable of received them.

TWO: Next you need to go into your ElasticSearch config file (elasticsearch.yml on the host server; mine was located at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml on a CentOS7 server). In this file you will find a "Network And HTTP" section. You will need to find the line that says:

`#http.port: 9200`

Uncomment this line and change the port to the port that you want ElasticSearch to run on. I chose 19200. Then do the same for the `#transport.tcp.port: 9300` setting. Again I chose 19300.

Lastly, at the end of this section (just for organizational sake, you could also simply append the following to the end of the file) add in:

`http.cors.allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.enabled: true`

You can change the above origin address to wherever your web server is serving Kibana from. Alternatively you could simply put `/.*/` to match all origins but this is not adviseable.

Now save the elasticsearch.yml file and restart the elasticsearch server. Your reverse proxy should be configured to run on port 9200 and point to 19200 if the request authenticates.

Word of warning, if you are using Cookies to authenticate requests you should make sure to white list the HTTP OPTIONS method in your reverse proxy configuration as only GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests include the cookies. I haven't tested whether OPTIONS include the Authentication header as well but it may be the same situation as the cookies. Kibana will not function correctly if the OPTIONS requests cannot get through as well.

It is also a good idea to configure your reverse proxy to blacklist any request that ends in _shutdown as this command shouldn't be needed via external requests in most cases.