# Kibana 3 with nginx ldap authentication - doesn't accept OPTIONS method?

Tags: authentication, nginx, elasticsearch, reverse-proxy

I have 2 virtual hosts on the same nginx server, that both use the [nginx-auth-ldap](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap) module.
the first virtual host is authenticating with ldap using nginx-auth-ldap, then forwards the request to the second virtual host which is a reverse proxy to my elasticsearch server. My problem is that the second virtual host should have ldap authentication enabled too. 
I've used the information from this post's answer : 
[How and where to implement basic authentication in Kibana 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867663/how-and-where-to-implement-basic-authentication-in-kibana-3/28530311#28530311)

1) Changed Kibana's config.js to -

```
elasticsearch: {server: "http://localhost:9200", withCredentials: true},
```

2) Change my elasticsearch.yaml to have the following :

```
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

But now when I send requests to Kibana, its saying that the Connection Failed, and the requests that I see failing are the OPTIONS requests that get 401 Unauthorized. The next step on the previous post says that I need to- "white list the HTTP OPTIONS method in your reverse proxy configuration as only GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests include the cookies."

How can I do this ?

Thanks.